# Weird memory leak using @dynamic properties: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, memory-leaks

I'm trying to do something similar to the @dynamic example Book.m written by Michael Dippery:

https://gist.github.com/mtt2p/7769576

For testing, I've wrote a modification to it in order to reproduce the problem. First, I've  created a header file for book.m:

```
@interface Book : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
}
@property (retain) NSString *title;
@property (retain) NSString *author;
@end
```

I've commented dealloc method, because  I'm using ARC:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "book.h"


@implementation Book
@dynamic title, author;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [data setObject:@"Tom Sawyer" forKey:@"title"];
        [data setObject:@"Mark Twain" forKey:@"author"];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
- (void)dealloc
{
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}*/

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSString *sel = NSStringFromSelector(selector);
    if ([sel rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@:@"];
    } else {
        return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"@@:"];
    }
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)invocation
{
    NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector([invocation selector]);
    if ([key rangeOfString:@"set"].location == 0) {
        key = [[key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [key length]-4)] lowercaseString];
        NSString *obj;
        [invocation getArgument:&obj atIndex:2];
        [data setObject:obj forKey:key];
    } else {
        NSString *obj = [data objectForKey:key];
        [invocation setReturnValue:&obj];
    }
}

@end

int lala(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Book *book = [[Book alloc] init];
    printf("%s is written by %s\n", [book.title UTF8String], [book.author UTF8String]);
    book.title = @"1984";
    book.author = @"George Orwell";
    printf("%s is written by %s\n", [book.title UTF8String], [book.author UTF8String]);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I've created a test ViewController with one "textfield" and one "button". Here is the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Caja;

@end
```

and here is the rest of code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "book.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Boton:(id)sender {
    Book *book = [[Book alloc] init];

    printf("%s is written by %s\n", [book.title UTF8String], [book.author UTF8String]);
    book.title = self.Caja.text; // <-- Line causing the error when this method ends
    book.author = @"George Orwell";
    printf("%s is written by %s\n", [book.title UTF8String], [book.author UTF8String]);    
}
```

If I assign a constant NSString to book.title, there is no memory problem. But If I try to assing dynamically a value to it, I always get the same error when Boton method ends: -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2fecbfe0

This is the trace of this error obtained with instrument:

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   Malloc  +1  1   00:36.665.061   Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:]
1   Autorelease         00:36.665.064   UIKit   -[UITextField text]
2   Retain  +1  2   00:36.665.066   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
    CFRetain/Release (2)            00:36.665.166   TestRESTController  -[Book forwardInvocation:]
3    CFRetain   +1  3   00:36.665.166   TestRESTController  -[Book forwardInvocation:]
4    Release    -1  2   00:36.665.168   TestRESTController  -[Book forwardInvocation:]
5   Release -1  1   00:36.665.170   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
6   Retain  +1  2   00:36.665.278   TestRESTController  -[Book forwardInvocation:]
7   Release -1  1   00:36.665.281   TestRESTController  -[Book forwardInvocation:]
8   Retain  +1  2   00:36.665.283   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
    Retain/Autorelease/Release (3)          00:36.665.284   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
9    Retain +1  3   00:36.665.284   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
10   Autorelease            00:36.665.285   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
13   Release    -1  0   00:36.667.441   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
11  Release -1  2   00:36.665.369   TestRESTController  -[ViewController Boton:]
12  CFRelease   -1  1   00:36.665.401   TestRESTController  -[Book .cxx_destruct]
14  Zombie      -1  00:36.667.612   UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
```

PD: Please, forgive me any writing error. I don't speak English.

Comment: Sorry, but I should have said that I'll use this in an abstract class which has to get dynamically the properties names (introspection) of a child class.

Comment: At first I though your dynamic properties were not being retained, but they're going into that mutable dictionary, so it looks ok. . I don't know what's wrong. A suggestion: In general I find IMP_implementationWithBlock easier than forward invocation. (Also apparently it's much faster)

Comment: Finally, I have decided to work around the problem. I have "synthesized" all properties and managed they later with `[self setValue:value forKey:property]` and `[self valueForKey:property]`. But I still am very interested in a solution for this problem.